# DateTime from vb.net to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

So I'm trying to convert a code from .NET to C#
Here's the code:

```
While getReader.Read

        ' getting the time in and time out 12 hour format
        time_in = (getReader.Item("time_in").ToString)
        time_out = (getReader.Item("time_out").ToString)

        With Listview1.Items.Add(getReader.Item("worker_fullname").ToString)

            .SubItems.Add(Format(time_in, "h:mm:ss tt"))
            .SubItems.Add(Format(time_out, "h:mm:ss tt"))
            .SubItems.Add(Format(getReader.Item("date"), "MMM dd, yyyy"))

        End With

    End While
```

Online code conversion does not help me at all. I'm having difficulty in `(getReader.Item("time_in").ToString)`. I tried `DateTime.TryParseExact(getReader[3], "h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out time_in);` but it says that it cannot convert from object to string.
And in the `End` and `End With`, it seems that C# doesn't have an equivalent language construct for that.

Comment: You should show your c# code as well.

Comment: Ditch the "code converter".  What do you want your C# code to *do*?  What is the functionality you wish to achieve?  What code have you written to achieve that functionality?  In what way does it not work as expected?

Comment: What is the time of the `time_in`, `time_out` fields? If it's `DateTime` you don't need nor should you convert or parse anything. Just cast the value to `DateTime`. This should be done in the VB.NET code as well. It's actually a *bug* to use strings instead of dates

Comment: In fact the VB.NET code wouldn't work at all if VB.NET didn't parse strings back into DateTime values

Answer (score 0):

Call `ToString()`:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(getReader[3].ToString(), "h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out time_in);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var timeIn = reader["time_in"].ToString();
    var timeOut = reader["time_out"].ToString();
    var workerFullName = reader["worker_fullname"].ToString();
    var date = reader["date"].ToString();

    //move to utility method 
    DateTime timeInDateTime;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(timeIn, "h:mm:ss tt", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeInDateTime);

    DateTime timeOutDateTime;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(timeOut, "h:mm:ss tt", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeOutDateTime);

    DateTime dateParsed;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MMM dd, yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateParsed);

    //add to list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WITH ... END WITH does not have equivalent in C# (regardless of how much I'd like it).
One has to assign it to a local variable such as:

```
...
var item = Listview1.Items.Add(getReader.Item("worker_fullname").ToString);
item.SubItems.Add($"{time_in, "h:mm:ss tt"))
...
```

As for getting data from reader it depends on how are those data stored in storage (database). In your case i guessc either getReader.GetString(3) or getReader.GetDateTime(3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(getReader.Item("time_in").Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(reader["time_in"].toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));